# Delete Query has failed: near "DELETE": syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-delete

I am doing a query  which is supposed to delete rows containing a specific string:

```
DELETE FROM Event 
WHERE EventMessage LIKE '%Missing format string - selector:%' 
IN
Select WhenOccurred,EventMessage
From Event
Where WhenOccurred > DateFunc('now', -1)
```

I have looked at all the documentation about deleting  and like statements but  I can not figure out the why this error shows up:

> Query has failed: near "DELETE": syntax error

Comment: what are trying to acheive Malcode? I dont understand the part In select ...

Comment: Try to show some sample data and explain how they should look like once the delete query is executed.

Comment: @zip from documentation I  am trying to remove rows that contain this string `'%Missing format string - selector:%' ` in the last 24 hrs

Comment: Are you on MySQL

Comment: @zip just standard SQL

Comment: `DateFunc('now', -1)` is not "standard SQL" [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
DELETE FROM Event 
WHERE EventMessage LIKE '%Missing format string - selector:%' ;

Select WhenOccurred,EventMessage
From Event
Where WhenOccurred >  NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am also pulling data as well with my select statement

Comment: @Malcode, they have to be two separaete queries: 1 for the delete and 2 for the select. I have the 2 separated by ;

Answer (score 0):

Your Question seems incomplete

If you just want to delete the record  having event message like  '%Missing format string - selector:%' then run your first query only

```
DELETE FROM Event 
WHERE EventMessage LIKE '%Missing format string - selector:%'
```

or if you want to add more condition like delete events occurred in last 24 hours

```
DELETE FROM Event 
WHERE EventMessage LIKE '%Missing format string - selector:%' and WhenOccurred >= DATEADD(hh, -24, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I want to delete the records having event message like '%Missing format string - selector:% and I want to (if possible) use my select statment to see the events now that I removed records containing missing format

Comment: you want to delete the record and retrieve the deleted record in same query?..what programming language are you using ?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: In that case either you have to do two queries first one for retrieving records and second one for deleting.  Or write a stored procedure which does both

Comment: @Malcode: which DBMS product are you using? In Postgres you could do that using `delete from ... returning *` other DBMS products might have a similar feature